# Use gcc On ELKS

Tags: gcc, embedded, ld, device-emulation

I'm using [PocketDOS](http://www.pocketdos.com/) to emulate [ELKS](http://elks.sourceforge.net/), but I want to develop on it using `gcc` and `ld`, how can I do this?

Comment: I assume you know ELKS has a C compiler already. Another more mature open source platform for 80186 and older processors is Minix 2: http://minix1.woodhull.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look, it seems that PocketDOS is based on an Intel 80186 emulation. 80186 does not support 32 bit protected mode, so you won't even be able to run DJPP (which is a GCC implementation for DOS) on it since that requires a DOS extender (DPMI) to support 32bit protected mode code.  An 80186 is essentially an 8086 with integrated on chip peripherals such as interrupt and DMA controllers.

I don't think you will be able to do this.  You will need a 16bit real-mode DOS compiler.

Comment: Scroll a little bit on the Download page and you will see that you can see some plugins to emulate CPUs. For example: `Bochs i80486DX CPU emulator plug-in for PocketDOS`. With this will be possible to run such programs?

Comment: Here: http://www.pocketdos.com/specifications.htm it certainly says other CPU's via third-party plugins.  If you can get it to emulate 386 DJPP should run.  However, you will need the emulator to run on your ultimate target, not just a PC.

Comment: I'm going to use BOCHS for WinCE to emulate the compiled OS.

Comment: Of course, it must be mentioned that ELKS has a C compiler. Just so you guys know.

Answer (score 0):

Directly, under ELKS, you can't - because there's no compiler ported to ELKS, as far as I'm aware (2023).

You can, however, develop programs for ELKS on another  32bit computer (and probably also on 64bit), using the dev tools used to build ELKS (presently fork of gcc-ia16; previously bcc).